# Pausing/Stopping YouTube video when hiding popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I've been researching to find an answer but can't seem to figure out how to get this youtube video to stop playing when the popup window is hidden. Here is my code...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  

            var id = '#dialog';

            //Get the screen height and width
            var maskHeight = $(document).height();
            var maskWidth = $(window).width();

            //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
            $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

            //transition effect     
            $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
            $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

            //Get the window height and width
            var winH = $(window).height();
            var winW = $(window).width();

            //Set the popup window to center
            $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
            $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

            //transition effect
            $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

        //if close button is clicked
        $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
            //Cancel the link behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#mask').hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });     

        //if mask is clicked
        $('#mask').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });

    });
    </script>

    </head>

<body>

<div id="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" class="window">

    <a href="#" class="close"><img src="exit_button.png" width="25" height="25" style="float:right;" /></a>

    <br />
    <br />

    <iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9SgIIlloQ5U?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div>
    <!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
    <div id="mask"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a javascript novice which may become apparent to you but I just need a simple solution to make this work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the YouTube API to generate a player and control it from your page using JavaScript. The full documentation for this is here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Essentially what you need to do is embed the video in the page as an object using this URL rather than the iframe:

https://www.youtube.com/v/9SgIIlloQ5U?version=3&enablejsapi=1

This loads the player and video of choice and enables the JavaScript API. You can then use these methods to control the player: Fire `player.playVideo()` when you need to start the video and `player.pauseVideo()` when you need to pause it.

There's loads of other things you can do with the API too - all the info is in the links provided.